# Fundamental theorem of Calculus question (GRE Math Subject Test #24 Year 2005)

Tags: calculus

Moviation: I am preparing for the GRE Math Subject and came across this question:

$$ h(x) = \int_0^{x^2} e^{x+t}\,dt$$

Then we have to find $h’(1)$. I know how to solve this problem directly and using FTC. However I was wondering what the solution would be if it was changed to $e^{x^2 +t^2}$.Please note that I am only interested using FTC and not doing it directly.

Full disclosure: The original question was given by ETS on their 2005 test available on the internet.

Comment: Over here the function $e^{x^2}$ can be taken outside and things become simple as shown by @user608571, for general functions you can use Leibniz integral rule, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x)=\int_{0}^{x^{2}}e^{x^{2}+t^{2}}~dt=e^{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}e^{t^{2}}~dt$. Then using the product rule and the FTC, we have $$h
'(x)=2xe^{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x^{2}}e^{t^{2}}dt+e^{x^{2}}\cdot2xe^{x^{4}}.$$ Evaluating at $x=1$ gives us $$h'(1)=2e\int_{0}^{1}e^{t^{2}}~dt+2e^{2},$$ although the integral cannot be found using closed forms.